# Updation in tables involving multiple conditions (one to many relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created three tables like Product, Brands and ProductBrands in ms sql server
These tables contains data as the following

Products (PId - PName - PDescription)

- 1 - Mobiles - blah blah
- 2 - T.V - blah blah
- 3 - A.C - blah blah

Brands (BId - BName)

- 1 - Samsung
- 2 - Sony
- 3 - L.G
- 4 - Apple

ProductsBrands (PBId - PId - BId)

- 1 - 1 - 1
- 2 - 1 - 2
- 3 - 1 - 3
- 4 - 2 - 1
- 5 - 2 - 3

...

...

Now I have to perform update operation on Product tables on the following conditions

- If user will select product "let's say Mobile", and he will select Samsung and L.G only
  so for this requirement, the updation in ProductsBrands should be like this

ProductsBrands (PBId - PId - BId)

- 1 - 1 - 1
- {2 - 1 - 2} should be deleted
- 3 - 1 - 3

...

...

- If user will select product "let's say Mobile", and he will select Apple
  so for this requirement, the updation in ProductsBrands should be like this

ProductsBrands (PBId - PId - BId)

- 1 - 1 - 1
- 2 - 1 - 2
- 3 - 1 - 3
- 4 - 2 - 1
- 5 - 2 - 3
- 6 - 1 - 4 {new entry is made}
- If user will select product "let's say Mobile", and he will select Samsung, L.G  and Apple
  so for this requirement, the updation in ProductsBrands should be like this

ProductsBrands (PBId - PId - BId)

- 1 - 1 - 1
- {2 - 1 - 2} should be deleted
- 3 - 1 - 3
- 4 - 2 - 1
- 5 - 2 - 3
- 6 - 1 - 4 {new entry is made}

Now I am very very confused how to write stored procedure for all above conditions

Please help me!!!

Comment: it looks like there is some design problems, not sure what the ProductsBrands is supposed to hold. It looks more like it should be dynamic rather than persisted data. But if you are stuck with that design probably triggers will help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually there is one to many relationship between products and brands in this example (one product has many brands). That is why I have created table ProductsBrands storing their relationship. If anything is wrong with the design please let me know that!!!

Comment: yes, I see that is used as junction table but not sure why the deletions; it's like every user input will yield a different table so why is it persisted and not just dynamically created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario was a little ambiguous for me. So lets simplify it as follow, and check if I got it correct or not:
You want to Insert or Delete or even Update a record or a set of records in a table(let say tbl1), whenever a condition(let say con1) is correct(let say if con1 is correct then Insert should me made, otherwise Delete or Update should be made).
If this is what you are looking for, then you could make a use of MERGE statement([Read More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)). 
If this is what you are looking for, and you have problem with MERGE statement, please tell us to clarify it.
Other links:[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) and [Here](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/12/introduction-to-t-sql-merge-basics/)

Comment: I am not getting merge statement from the above link... please provide me any example on this scenario